# Можно ли от непереходного глагола "накурить" (первое значение) образовать причастие "накуренный"?

Tags: грамматика, краткое-причастие, предикатив

В источниках дается **противоречивая** информация. С одной стороны, существует наречие ***накурено***  с функцией сказуемого, то есть предикативное наречие, или слово категории состояния. *В комнате **накурено*** (дымно).

С другой стороны, при разборе ***накуренный*** называют то причастием, то прилагательным, а в книге Литневской о безличных предложениях сказано: ***накурено*** — краткое страдательное **причастие.**

Вот как тут быть пользователям языка, если в лингвистике есть такие **несоответствия?**

**МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ**

**НАКУРИТЬ,** -курю, -куришь; накуренный; -рен, -а, -о; св. **1. (чем). Куря, наполнить помещение табачным дымом.** Н. табаком, махоркой. // чем. Сжигая какое-л. ароматическое вещество, наполнить помещение ароматным дымом, запахом. Н. ладаном. Н. благовониями. 2. что и чего. Добыть, приготовить в каком-л. количестве путём перегонки (курения). Н. вина (устар.; о водке). Н. бочку смолы. Накуривать, -аю, -аешь; нсв.

**НАКУРЕНО**, **нареч., в функц. сказ**. (где). О наличии дыма от курения; о сильном запахе табачного дыма в помещении. Н. табаком, махоркой. Здесь очень н.!

**[Литневская, стр. 80](https://bookscafe.net/read/litnevskaya_elena-russkiy_yazyk_kratkiy_teoreticheskiy_kurs-5758.html#p80)**

2. глагол-связка в безличной форме + краткое с**традательное причастие**:
   В комнате было накурено.

Comment: Это словарь Кузнецова?

Comment: У Лопатина тоже причастие. И не только.

Comment: У Ефремовой предикатив,  а что это значит?  В орфографическом словаре 
накурено, в знач. сказ. А что это значит? Глагол непереходный или переходный?  Можно от него образовать причастие? Где именно у Лопатина написано, что это причастие?

Comment: НАКУРЕННЫЙ
Большой толковый словарь
НАКУРЕННЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Наполненный, пропитанный табачным дымом. Какой в комнате н. воздух. Мы вошли в н-ое помещение.  Это прилагательное?